# Authenticating Apollo client for AppSync to work with @aws_subscribe

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync, api-key

I'm using API_KEY authentication with AppSync and it works fine for queries and mutations.

Having hard time getting it to work with @aws_subscribe subscriptions. Here is how I try to get the connection:

```
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/client/link/ws'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context'

import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  split,
} from "@apollo/client"

import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities'

import { API_URI, API_KEY, REALTIME_API_URI } from "@env"

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = API_KEY
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
    },
  }
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: API_URI,
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: REALTIME_API_URI,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    lazy: true,
  },
})

const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query)
    return (
      kind === 'OperationDefinition'
      && operation === 'subscription'
    )
  },
  authLink.concat(wsLink),
  authLink.concat(httpLink),
)

export const gqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
// console.log({ API_URI }, { API_KEY })
```

As I understand, this questions is asked a lot -- still I'm not able to find satisfactory answer. There is evidence that the latest Apollo client stopped being compatible with AppSync authentication for web sockets, still wondering if there is some kinds of a work around (hack) to pass API_KEY to the appsync subscription so it does not not reject the request and establishes the connection. I really would like to avoid using Amplify, as well as building SNS pub sub myself. Really curious if anyone was able to get this simpler use case to work and can share some sample code.

Here is how I subscribe in the client:

```
const subscription = CONST.gqlClient
      .subscribe({
        query: gql`
        subscription onSendMessage($chatUuid: String!) {
          onSendMessage (chatUuid: $chatUuid) {
            chatUuid
            createdAt
            messageUuid
            text
            updatedAt
            uuid          }
        }
        `,
        variables: {
          chatUuid,
        },
      })
      .subscribe({
        next(data) {
          console.log({ data })
        },
        error({ error }) {
          console.log({ error })
        },
        complete() { console.log("subs. DONE") }, // never printed
      })
```

When I run it, I do see in the log:

```
Object {
  "subscription": Subscription {
    "_cleanup": Subscription {
      "_cleanup": [Function anonymous],
      "_observer": Object {
        "complete": [Function complete],
        "error": [Function error],
        "next": [Function next],
      },
      "_queue": undefined,
      "_state": "ready",
    },
    "_observer": Object {
      "complete": [Function complete],
      "error": [Function error],
      "next": [Function next],
    },
    "_queue": undefined,
    "_state": "ready",
  },
}
```

But after that nothing ever happens, no error messages, no subscription messages trigger on the mutation invocation.
When I subscribe to this subscription in the aws console -- it does trigger just fine. I'm just never able to get it to work in the client app.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a solution which works.
It was as simple as using different Apollo clients for "queries" and "mutations" vs "subscriptions".
The complete solution can be found here:
https://www.echowaves.com/post/getting-apollo-client-to-work-with-aws_subscribe

Comment: Dmtry is this solution still working.? tried it. It is not working.

Getting this error. Any idea how to fix this ?

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "BadRequestException",
    "message" : "Subscriptions over MQTT is not supported."
  } ]
}

Comment: yes, it does work for me (that's why I posted the solution). Not sure what MQTT means. Perhaps, you are connecting to a different GraphQL server than I have? My GraphQL server implementation can be found here https://github.com/echowaves/WiSaw.cdk

Comment: The above solution no longer will work, By checking the repo(https://github.com/echowaves/WiSaw/blob/master/src/subscriptionClientWs.js) I have found @DmitryAmelchenko workaround :), Thanks